# Looking for a Sound Designer

Tags: film-sound-design

This is not really an AD, I'm not trying to spam the board. I'm looking for a sound guy in the NY area and have been having trouble finding someone. I've posted on craigslist but I either get nothing or craigslist takes down my ad.

Any recommendations guys?

Comment: Based on what I've read, it sound like you meant to ask for a Production Sound Mixer and Boom Operator, not a Sound Designer (Sound Designers are part of the post process).

Answer (score 5):

Try mandy.com as well as craigslist. Also, make sure you offer, at very least, a token compensation. There are so many ads on craigslist offering "credit and copy" (which should be a part of any working relationship anyway). I can imagine that a lot of the ads calling for volunteers would be flagged by people tired of seeing them. Even just $100 - whatever you can spare - would go a long way towards attracting someone who's serious about the role.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that in our technologically advantageous climate that Sound Designers don't need to be local unless there's a specific situation that requires it. I do remote work all the time. 99% of the time actually. And yes, as @Roger mentioned, please offer some form of compensation. Any of us worth our salt or worth hiring really has no need for credit and copy or food service meals. Integrity alone is worth more than any of that.

Comment: +1.  I've done a lot of work for NYC clients among other localtes from my studio in LA.  Didn't hinder the process at all, we dealt via FTP for content and phone/email for discussion.  Was a breeze.

Comment: "Any of us worth our salt or worth hiring really has no need for credit and copy or food service meals. Integrity alone is worth more than any of that." I'm gonna quote you on that. Awesome words!

Answer (score 1):

The mythical creatures appear only during times of great need...

Answer (score 0):

Someone got the job? ;-)
I do 90% of my work in my own studio, using the internet for data transmission (mostly FTP). I think this the way for not really big budgets - and maybe even for big ones ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot guys. Being a low budget filmmaker I gues I was confused about the appropriate wording for such jobs. I just know how awful sound can be on production and I wanted to make sure I got the right person. I got a boom operator which I take is all I need at this point?

Comment: Ideally you want a location recordist [i]and[/i] a boom op. unless the recordist/op is experienced enough to handle both and the production isn't too crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I am a sound designer. I will have my MFA in May 2012. What is the project that you want to sound design for? What is the address? How much is the compensation? If you are still looking for a sound designer contact me on ial@gm.slc.edu